# passing data from database to foreach loop, error in json array

Tags: php, arrays

I am retrieving data from the database using a modal in Codeigniter, and when I pass the data to an array using foreach loop, It is giving the error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\base_codeigniter\application\controllers\User.php on line 32

I want to show the json data in a table in the View page.

What is wrong on the line 32

```
        foreach ($get_data as $data) {
        $show_table = array(
                             'name':$data['name'],  // Line 32
                             'email':$data['email'], // Line 33
                             'phone':$data['phone']
                        );
        echo json_encode($show_table);                

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
$show_table = array(
    'name' => $data['name'],  // Line 32
    'email' => $data['email'], // Line 33
    'phone' => $data['phone']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing -  your syntax is wrong. It should be as suggested by @Ashwin Garg in the answer below, which is

```
$show_table = array(
    'name' => $get_data['name'],  // Line 32
    'email' => $get_data['email'], // Line 33
    'phone' => $get_data['phone']
);
```

Second issue is that you should use `get_data` variable inside the loops which represent the current object. `$data` is the iterable object that you want to loop through not the individual element of that object.